# NGINX config only picks up root, otherwise is sending to error screen without alias

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx, laravel-forge

I'm attempting to link a particular subdirectory of my existing laravel site over to a wordpress installation. For some reason the root works, but all subdirectories of the root of the wordpress are not pointing to that folder.

I've attempted to add in wild cards to the location that is pointing over, but it doesn't seem to want to pick it up.

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name .swyftfilings.us;
        root /home/forge/swyftfilings.us/public;

        # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/swyftfilings.us/457933/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/swyftfilings.us/457933/server.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        charset utf-8;

        # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
        include forge-conf/swyftfilings.us/server/*;

        location /learning-center {

            alias /home/forge/learning-center/public;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;


            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
            }

        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        access_log off;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/swyftfilings.us-error.log error;

        error_page 404 /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
            deny all;
        }
    }

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/swyftfilings.us/after/*;
```

Expected the url sub directory /learning-center/{anything here} to search within the 'learning-center/public' directory, however only /learning-center does.

EDIT: It looks like it will work, but only with files ending in .php